# django-filebrowser fails during testing

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

Error message:

```
Creating Test for the FileBrowser site: filebrowser
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..................D:\blizzard\Projects\Python\Web\moz455\venv\lib\site-packages\
django\template\defaulttags.py:1235: DeprecationWarning: The syntax for the url
template tag is changing. Load the `url` tag from the `future` tag library to st
art using the new behavior.
  category=DeprecationWarning)
('path:', 'uploads/tmp_test_0\\testimage_medium.jpg')
FRemoving left-over tmp dir: uploads/tmp_test_0

======================================================================
FAIL: runTest (filebrowser.tests.sites.TestSite_filebrowser)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\blizzard\Projects\Python\Web\moz455\venv\lib\site-packages\filebrowse
r\tests\sites.py", line 233, in runTest
    test_detail(self)
  File "D:\blizzard\Projects\Python\Web\moz455\venv\lib\site-packages\filebrowse
r\tests\sites.py", line 140, in test_detail
    test.assertTrue(test.site.storage.exists(path))
AssertionError: False is not True
```

I wrote about it on filebrowser's github page, but maybe it's my own fault. Can this problem be solved without dealing with filebrowser source?
Note: path is equal to 'uploads/tmp_test_0\\testimage_medium.jpg', folder 'uploads' is in application 'media' folder
Versions: Django - 1.4.1, django-filebrowser - 3.5.0, django-grappelli - 2.4.0

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in the path (`uploads/tmp_test_0\\testimage_medium.jpg`)?

Comment: It's the output of "print path" command, I cannot say more